# JavaScript replace part of string regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hey guys i need to replace a string which starts every time with the same parts. Such as…

```
var name = $('.item').attr('name'); // Could be »item-name-XYZ« (XYZ) differs each time.
name.replace('item-name-?', 'item-name-newone');
```

items can appear many times and i do have to replace all names of them. I guess its something with regex…

Thanks in advance.

BTW: My most asked questions are about regex. Does someone has a good source to learn it?

Comment: This question seems odd as formulated, do you wish to change the name attribute of those elements?  Otherwise a simple `name="item-name-newone";` has the same net effect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is about regex. You can learn them [here](http://regexone.com/)

Your code will look like this:

```
name.replace(/item-name-(.*)/, 'item-name-newone');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, you can use javascript

```
var newone = name.substr(0,10) + 'Xyy';
```